# Suppose I have fetched the testcase as tags from the excel file, how do I execute these testcases as a cucumber option tags using junit?

Tags: junit5, cucumber-junit

I have one excel file which has list of test cases ex: Smoketest, Smketest1(these are the tags of each scenario in feature file)
Now I have a method to fetch these data from excel which gives output like @Smoketest, @smoketest1 etc

Now how do I pass these tags to cucumber option to run them? I tried using junit but its not working and not throwing any error

```
public static void main(String\[\] args) throws IOException
{
SmokeTest cucumberOptions = new SmokeTest();
cucumberOptions.setOptions();//this method gives tags and links tags to cucumber options
JUnitCore junitRunner = new JUnitCore();
junitRunner.run(SmokeTest.class);
}
```

Also to link the testcases I have used below line

```
`System.setProperty("cucumber.options",+tags);`
```

my runner file is as below

```
`import java.io.IOException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@CucumberOption
(
features = ".\\src\\test\\resources\\features\\", monochrome = true,
extraGlue = {"test\\connect\\stepdefinition",},
plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty","pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
"json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
"rerun:target/rerun.txt"}
// tags=""

)`
```

The tags fetched from excel are not passed here. How do i link them?